# How to rescue a dead Eeepc

Tags: boot, freeze, eee-pc

I have a neighbour's Eeepc 901 that seems dead.  It has been temperamental for days.  It would start Windows XP and seem ok only to freeze with a black screen after some hours.  In this state the three green LEDs would be illuminated (ie all except Wifi).  The only way to wake it would be to press and hold the power button which would shut it down.  Pressing again would wake it up normally and it would boot.

Yesterday it did this again but after powering down, pressing the power button just returned it to the three LEDs lit state without booting.  I have tried removing power and removing the battery.  Plugging in the power and pushing the power button does nothing (maybe this is normal). Plugging the battery back in and pushing the power button returned it to three green LEDs state.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I can try?

Comment: It sounds a little like it is going into hibernation, which is not well behaved.  Similar to http://superuser.com/questions/823431/laptop-not-turning-on#comment1082260_823431.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that is possible, although the LEDs would not be on in that case.  It has now come back to life and I discover it has license issues...

Comment: Among other issues

Comment: Windows XP is long past its end of life. It's time to install a supported operating system or purchase a new computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try gently squeezing the power supply bayonet that goes into the Netbook with a pair of pliers. This will slightly widen the sides of the outer part of the bayonet and make a better contact on the Netbook. It worked for me